# How cut throw a line with a random amount of numberpairs

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following line

```
FileName|1.0.0.0 2.0.0.0 3.0.0.4 4.0.1.2 #.... and so on
```

I check if this file exists

```
if [ -f /srv/torrentfiles/$film.torrent ]
then
```

and now i want to do something for every number pair like:

```
while there is a new NumberPair(1.0.0.0)
do somthing with NumberPair
```

But how can i do that, because i don´t know how much number pairs there will be.
Is there a possibility for shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to extract the filename from the line, then just iterate over the numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash
line='FileName|1.0.0.0 2.0.0.0 3.0.0.4 4.0.1.2'
filename=${line%|*}
for pair in ${line#*|} ; do
    echo "$filename" "$pair"
done
```